# sample distribution such that points are farthest apart

Tags: sampling

I need to plot some stuff and want to choose colors such that they are as distinct as possible.
Given a [0,1]^n cube how should one sample points without knowing beforehand the number of samples and at the same time the points are farthest apart on average?

Comment: Distance in color space is not generally a good predictor of visual "distinctness".